# Javascript array find alternative

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

I'm looking for an alternative for the `find()` method of an array. I'm using it on Android Browser and `Array.prototype.find()` doesn't work there. [Definition Array Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
var test= this.arrayOfValues.find(function (value) {
            return (value.name === device.value)
});
```

Comment: please have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill

Comment: Thanks Nina. It work's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not care so much about programming your own, and if [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is somehow not usable, have a look at [`Underscore.js#find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find). As an alternative, as @NinaScholz recommended in the comments, use the [Polyfill from mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill):

> ```
> if (!Array.prototype.find) {
>   Array.prototype.find = function(predicate) {
>     if (this === null) {
>       throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
>     }
>     if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
>       throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
>     }
>     var list = Object(this);
>     var length = list.length >>> 0;
>     var thisArg = arguments[1];
>     var value;
>
>     for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
>       value = list[i];
>       if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
>         return value;
>       }
>     }
>     return undefined;
>   };
> }
> ```

Comment: Using Polyfill from mozilla work's very well. Thanks.